# split file and pass split parts as file, not pipe to stdin

Tags: gnu-parallel

How to take file (`seq 1000000`), split it into multiple smaller ones, which will be then passed into process as a file, not a pipe? I.e.

```
parallel -a <(seq 1000000) -j 6 -l 10000 <what here?> /root/someProcess
```

where `someProcess` will process the part as:

```
/root/someProcess <(seq 500)
```

i.e. it will take file as a parameter and process it.

Comment: User @OleTange is actually the main author of that tool :) He's also active here, but many GNU Parallel questions get posted over at [Unix.Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnu-parallel); I'd consider migrating the question there (UNIX.SE has a rule against questions that are posted to multiple sites).

Comment: I'd do that, but I see same (small) number of questions there, and I don't see any way how to easily migrate. Lets keep it here and we will see if it gets any traction. Meanwhile I'll rewrite my code without parallel.

Comment: there's 47 [tag:gnu-parallel] questions here, and 244 over there; you have a bit of a loose definition of "same (small) number" :) But yeah, I think leaving it here for a while is a good course of action.

Comment: @MarcusMüller you're correct, my bad. Btw. is there some transfer command, or does it mean delete here and recreate there?

Answer (score 0):

`<(seq 1000000)` is not a regular file. It creates a fifo that can only be read once.

To use that with GNU Parallel you use `--pipe`:

```
seq 1000000 | parallel --pipe ...
```

If, OTOH, you have a regular big file, look at [split file and pass split parts as stdin](https://superuser.com/questions/1761946/split-file-and-pass-split-parts-as-stdin)

Comment: my bad then, sadly I'm not that familiar with linux. I can update the question to: seq 1000000 > /tmp/a , and then use … -a /tmp/a. This is what I tried to ask. How to split input and pass it into target command as a files. Or is it nonsense as it does nto pose any performance benefit? Sorry for confusion

Comment: @MartinMucha Use `--pipepart`. See https://superuser.com/questions/1761946/split-file-and-pass-split-parts-as-stdin