# split file and pass split parts as stdin

Tags: gnu-parallel

Tutorial explains:

```
The input source can be a file:

parallel -a abc-file echo
```

but how this actually work? I'd like to take input file: `seq 1000` and process it through pipe, but I cannot find way anywhere.

attempt 1:

```
parallel --verbose -a <(seq 50) -l 10 -j 5 echo
```

--> this just takes 50 lines, split it by 10 and calls echo with 10 arguments. We don't want this.

attempt 2:

```
parallel -a <(seq 50) -l 10 -j 5 --pipe cat
```

will just 'hang', because:

```
seq 5 | parallel -a <(seq 50) -l 10 -j 5 --pipe cat
```

it does not read from file but from stdin.

What is the correct way of reading from file and producing parts into file stdin?

Ok, I know I can write:

```
seq 50 | parallel -l 10 -j 5 --pipe wc -l
```

but I'd really like parallel to read it out of file(I assume this could be faster, than bash pipe), but for some reason this does not work either as result is 50, meaning splitting by 10 did not work here. And ok, lets say that's it's fast, so limit of -j 5 wasn't reached, so if we try:

```
seq 50 | parallel -l 10 -j 5 --pipe bash -c 'wc -l;sleep 1;'
```

I'd expect 5 lines of 10 to be produced, but instead:

```
 50      50     141
```

is. Why is that?

Comment: it shouldn't as it asked different thing.

Comment: In that case, my apologies

Comment: Does this answer your question? [split file and pass split parts as file, not pipe to stdin](https://superuser.com/questions/1761942/split-file-and-pass-split-parts-as-file-not-pipe-to-stdin)

Comment: @Toto. No. This is my own question asking about different thing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `--pipe-part`:

```
seq 100000000 > bigfile
parallel --pipe-part -a bigfile --block -1 wc
```

---

As to why your tries fail: `--pipe` only reads from stdin. It is because it can be combined with `:::`, `::::`, and `-a`.

A simple (not very useful) example that does the same thing in 3 different ways:

```
seq 460000 | parallel --pipe --tag grep {} ::: 1 2 3
seq 3 > 3file
seq 460000 | parallel --pipe --tag grep {} :::: 3file
seq 460000 | parallel --pipe --tag -a 3file grep {}
```

Comment: thanks for answer! I tried it, and it works in oversimlified example, but I'm not sure if it's not just coincidence. I did not try it before, since pipepart says, that it partition input per block by somewhat fixed size, while for me the indivisible minimum is one line. I didn't know about negative blocks before and I don't understand it fully still, but it does not seem to be, that it prevents line splits. But maybe the original question is pointless; I just wanted to try if reading directly from file instead of pipe offers some performance benefit; it there isn't really, pipe would be fine

Comment: @MartinMucha Why do you feel the block is fixed? Why do you feel GNU Parallel does not split at `--recend`/`--recstart`?